# Bootstrap 4 and background color in a table cell

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, tablecell

I work with Boostrap 4: I have a table cell that looks like this:

[image: Table cell and background color]

I want the background color to cover the whole cell.

How do I go about removing the white line that appears between the bottom border of the cell and the background color of the cell?

The code I use is:

```
<td  align="center">
                     <h6>
                         <small>
                        <div  class="background-color: p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">
                              I.E.C.A. (A2)
                              Ingreso Abogacía (UNC) Enero
                        </div>
                      </small>
                     </h6>
  </td>
```

Comment: Disregarding the improper markup, you are adding margin to bottom of the `<div>` with class `mb-2` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/#notation

Comment: Thank you very much Arleigh Hix! your answer is as simple as it is correct.
I add a question: Why is my code "Disregarding the improper markup"?

Comment: Element div not allowed as child of element small in this context. https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: The align attribute on the td element is obsolete.

Comment: Ok. Very useful your clarification and the link to expand my knowledge. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You should be applying those bootstrap classes to the `<td>`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/becf38g9/

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here. You have a DIV which is a BLOCK element, inside of a SMALL tag which is an INLINE element. Inline elements usually have a line-height property with a value greater than 1, so that creates vertical space around the element. Set that element to "display:block" and that will fix that issue. Secondly, those elements are inside of an H2 tag, which is a block element, but usually has a "margin-bottom" by default. Remove the margin from the H2 tag and it should work for you. So something like the below, although you should use a stylesheet instead of inline css.

Read more about inline elements here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#elements

```html
<td align="center">
  <h6 style="margin:0;">
    <small style="display:block;">
                        <div  class="background-color: p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">
                              I.E.C.A. (A2)
                              Ingreso Abogacía (UNC) Enero
                        </div>
                      </small>
  </h6>
</td>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried your solution but it doesn't work. The correct solution was given in Arleigh Hix's comment.

Comment: Yes, that was a great catch by Arleigh Hix. Do keep in mind the difference between block and inline elements though, as that is a huge part of HTML. In this code you may even be able to remove the DIV, and SMALL tags, and just apply to Bootstrap classes to the H6.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and suggestions! I am a beginner in the use of Bootstrap and therefore I make these mistakes